# Update conda version to 4.6.12?

Tags: python, updates, anaconda

I am struggling to update my conda version to the newest release of 4.6.12.

Using `conda update conda`  says all packages are up to date.

And using `conda update conda=4.6.12` results in a PackagesNotFoundError. Hence, typing `conda -V` still gives 4.6.11. Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
hokage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, don't try to update conda to 4.6.12 as there are some problems with it. Stick to conda 4.6.11 with python 3.6.5. It is best spot for doing anything with Python or Machine Learning or Data Science and if you still want to update then download anaconda from here and install it again
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
For python 3.6.5 download conda 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Continuum is breaking with "free" packages 
https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/

I personally would only use miniconda https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/